# Social Security Number SSN for Non Americans

Tags: immigration

I live in India, but few universities are demanding SSN,Can SSN be given to those people also who are trying to go to study in USA? I have never travelled to USA so far.

Comment: Be aware **many** US organization (schools, doctors, dentists, etc) will *ask* for an SSN expecting you to provide it without a second thought. However, the reality is **very few** *actually need* the SSN. To prevent identity theft, it is wise to *not* disclose an SSN to *anyone* other than a government office (IRS, DMV, Police, etc). I would press the school as to **why** they needed an SSN.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not need a social security number to register for school in the United States.  Call the school and tell them you do not have one, and find out if they require them for international students.

You may choose to get one if you intend to work in the United States and are authorized to do so.

See https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10096.pdf